# Convert NSArray into array of JSON objects

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, fmdb

I'd like to create a JSON array of objects from the resultsArray.

```
NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
FMResultSet *resultsSet = [database executeQuery:queryString];
while ([resultsSet next]) {
    [resultsArray addObject:[resultsSet resultDictionary]];
}
```

For clarification, I'm using FMDB to query a database. I'm then storing the resulting objects within the resultsArray. From here I want to convert that results array into a JSON array of objects.

Comment: So.. you want all the objects, not the dictionaries?

Comment: Are you asking how to use a JSON library in cocoa or something else? It's far from clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use NSJSONSerialization class to create a JSON file from your dictionary using the class method

```
NSData * JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:resultsArray
                                                    options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];
```

For more info look at [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)