# Dynamically store values from NSMutable Array into JSON Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am building an iOS app in Objective-C to track locations and I have 3 mutable arrays called time stamp, latitude and longitude. Now I need to pass these values to the django server in order to get locations back from the server.

How can I convert these values to a JSON? Also, my values are being dynamically updated depending on change in location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSArray into array of JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961590/convert-nsarray-into-array-of-json-objects)

Comment: Does your Django server have any requirements of the data you send to it? E.g. a certain json format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSJSONSerialization` can serialize any `Plist` compliant object. `([NS]Array/Dictionary/String/Number/Date/Data)`